# How to work with links that use javascript:window.location using Selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have dabbled with bits of simple code over the years. I am now interested in automating some repetitive steps in a web based CRM used at work. I tried a few automation tools. I was not able to get AutoIT to to work with the Chrome webdriver. I then tried WinTask and did not make meaningful progress. I started exploring Python and Selenium last week.

I now have automated the first few steps of my project by Googling about each step I wanted to achieve, learning from pages on Stackflow and other sites. Where I need help is that most of the links in the CRM are some sort of javascript links. Most of the text links or images have links that are formatted like this...

javascript:window.location = 'Reports/ResponseTimes.aspx?from=1%2f14%2f2021&to=1%2f14%2f2021&target=gn';

It looks like the many find_element_by functions in Selenium do not interact with the javascript links. Tonight I found a page that directed me to use... driver.execute_script(javaScript) ...Eventually I found an example that made it clear I should enter the javascript link into that function. This works...

driver.execute_script("window.location = 'Reports/ResponseTimes.aspx?from=1%2f14%2f2021&to=1%2f14%2f2021&target=gn';")

My issue is that I see now that the javascript links are actually and dynamically generated. In the code above the link gets updated with dates based on the current date. I can't reuse the driver.execute_script() code above since the dates have to be updated.

My hope is to find a way to code so that I can locate the javascript links I need based on some part of the link that does not change. The link above always has "target=gn" at the end and that is unique enough that if I could find and pull the current version of the link into a variable and then run it in driver.execute_script(), I believe that would solve my current issue.

I expect a solution could then be used in the next step I need to perform, where there a list of new leads that all needs to be updated in a manner that tells the system a human has reviewed the lead and "stopped the clock". To view each lead, there are more javascript links. Each link is unique since it includes a value that is the record number for the lead. Here's the first two...

javascript:top.viewItem(971244899);
javascript:top.viewItem(971312602);

I imagine that being able to search the page for some or all of... javascript:top.viewItem( ...in order to create a variable for... javascript:top.viewItem(971244899); ...so that it can be placed in... driver.execute_script() ...is the approach that is needed.

Thanks for any suggestions. I have made many searches on this site and Google for phrases that might teach me more about working with javascript links. I am asking for guidance since I have not been able to move forward on my own. Here's my current code...

```
import selenium
PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get("https://apps.vinmanager.com/cardashboard/login.aspx")
# log in
time.sleep(1)
search = driver.find_element_by_name("username")
search.send_keys("xxx")
search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
time.sleep(2)
search = driver.find_element_by_name("password")
search.send_keys("xxx")
search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
time.sleep(1)
# close news pop-up
driver.find_element_by_link_text("Close").click()
time.sleep(2)
# Nav to left pane
driver.switch_to.frame('leftpaneframe')
# Leads at No Contact link
driver.execute_script("window.location = 'Reports/ResponseTimes.aspx?from=1%2f14%2f2021&to=1%2f14%2f2021&target=gn';")
```

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I found enough info online to recognize that I needed to replace the "//a" tag in the xpath find method with the proper tag, which was "//area" in my case and then extract the href so that I could execute it...

```
## click no contact link ##
print('click no contact link...')
cncl = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//area[contains(@href,'target=gn')]").get_attribute('href')
time.sleep(2)
driver.execute_script(cncl)
```